# PlantUML create in a different direction

Tags: uml, direction, sequence-diagram, plantuml

is there a way to control where in a plantUML sequence diagram an object is created? 
Have a look at this simple example. Here I would like to have the GUI between the Console and the user.

[image]

The Code for this diagram looks like this:

```
 /*
 * 
 * @startuml
 * skinparam sequenceParticipant underline
 * 
 * actor User
 * participant "Console" 
 * database "DB"
 * activate User
 * 
 * User -> Console : giveMeGUI()
 * activate Console
 * create GUI
 * Console -> GUI
 * GUI -> User : Hi there 
 * @enduml
 */
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not in the UML specifications, the convention for ordering lifelines is generally depicted in the order in which they are first used and/or created. Having **GUI** appear before **Console** would at a moment's glance indicate that it is created/used before **Console**, though closer inspection would show that it is created by **Console**.

Is it maybe that you don't like the **GUI** response crossing over **Console**'s execution specification. If so, unless *giveMeGUI()*'s execution persist beyond GUI creation, it should be deactivated anyways.

For example

```
@startuml
skinparam sequenceParticipant underline

actor User
participant "Console" 
activate User

User -> Console : giveMeGUI()
activate Console
create GUI
Console -> GUI : <<create>>
deactivate Console
activate GUI
GUI -> User : Hi there 
deactivate GUI
database "DB"
@enduml
```

would result in the following

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that the sequence of the elements indicate anything. That was helpful.